# jMock - allowing() a call multiple times with different results

Tags: java, jmock

I want to call `allowing()` several times and provide different results. But I'm finding that the first `allowing()` specification absorbs all the calls and I can't change the return value.

```
@Test
public void example() {
    timeNow(100);
    // do something

    timeNow(105);
    // do something else
}

private void timeNow(final long timeNow) {
    context.checking(new Expectations() {{
        allowing(clock).timeNow(); will(returnValue(timeNow));
    }});
}
```

If I change `allowing(clock)` to `oneOf(clock)` it works fine. But ideally I want to use `allowing()` and not over-specify that the clock is called only once. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Had you used mockito, it would have been easy to specify... With jmock, though, no idea, sorry

Comment: Mockito's flexible, but I actually find jMock's pernicketiness useful normally: if it's hard to do in jMock, it means your design is bad. In this case, I think my design is OK and jMock's let me down. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at [states](http://www.jmock.org/states.html) - they allow you to change which expectation to use based on what "state" the test is in.

```
@Auto private States clockState;
@Test
public void example() {
    clockState.startsAs("first");
    timeNow(100);
    // do something

    clockState.become("second");
    timeNow(105);
    // do something else
}

private void timeNow(final long timeNow) {
    context.checking(new Expectations() {{
        allowing(clock).timeNow(); will(returnValue(timeNow));
        when(clockState.is("first"));

        allowing(clock).timeNow(); will(returnValue(timeNow + 100));
        when(clockState.is("second"));
    }});
}
```