# jmock reset object state

Tags: java, jmock, expectations

I have `HttpServletRequest` mock object and I want to reset `getHeader("someHeader")` multiple times. 
For example:

```
checking(new Expectations() {
  {
    allowing(request).getHeader("someHeader");
    will(returnValue(null));
  }
});
```

Do something here:

```
// getHeader returns null 

checking(new Expectations() {
  {
    allowing(request).getHeader("someHeader");
    will(returnValue("hello"));
  }
});
```

`getHeader` still returns `null`, once the object state is defined we can't change it? I wanted it to return "hello" for `getHeader`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at [states](http://www.jmock.org/states.html) - they allow you to change which expectation to use based on what "state" the test is in.

You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29158568/2796998).